# Meteor.js can't find semantic:ui package

Tags: javascript, meteor, less, package, semantic-ui

I'm looking at using Semantic UI in my meteor projects. When I try to run: `meteor add semantic:ui` I get an error from the terminal saying that the package doesn't exists, yet according the [Semantic UI](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI#additional-versions) GitHub page it should?

Comment: try with `meteor add nooitaf:semantic-ui`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`semantic:ui` is now Depcrecated , like they point on the [nooitaf:semantic-ui package Atmosphere README](https://atmospherejs.com/nooitaf/semantic-ui)

try with

```
meteor add semantic:ui-css
```

**Using Deprecated (not a good choose)**

```
meteor add nooitaf:semantic-ui
```

Comment: Isn't that just the compiled CSS, and doesn't support theming?

Comment: @colbyn i dont wanna answer "yes" or "no" but since `semantic:ui package` is pointing to that package, i think the best solution will be use the new package, also i have an app where i have the `semantic:ui package`, and i see a console.log who says **its time to move to the new semantic package**.

Comment: Upps seems like i didn't read the README **This package does not support theming and includes generated CSS files of the default theme only.** i just add the semantic into a project, running `meteor add nooitaf:semantic-ui`

Answer (score 0):

We're currently working on relaunching the package. We didnt correctly build the LESS theming into meteor's pipeline in the original package so it did not add any particular value over using `semantic:ui-css`.

The new package should launch in the next couple days and support theming.

**Edit**: We just launched the new package, won't be going away again :)
https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui